# Magento getAddToCartUrl() not working the same in all templates

Tags: php, magento

I use `<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>` in both `/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` and `/template/catalog/product/widget/sale/sale_default_list.phtml` to generate Add to Cart buttons.

Somehow, they generate different results, making the buttons in `sale_default_list.phtml` not working.

In `sale_default_list.phtml`, the url is like:
`checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL25ldy5qdGVjaGRpZ2l0YWwuY29tLw,,/product/54/form_key/84lfaneD1yV07mj4/`

While in `list.phtml`:
`/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL25ldy5qdGVjaGRpZ2l0YWwuY29tL2FwcGxlLWFjY2Vzc29yaWVzLmh0bWw,/product/54/form_key/84lfaneD1yV07mj4/`

You can see the token after `/uenc/` is really different. I am not really sure what's going on.

*UPDATE**-----------*

- *Sorry I was not listing the same product, it's edited.*
- *Typo in the path, it's actually `product/widget`*

Comment: This token is your current url which was encoded by base64. At the first case it's your home page and at the second case it's category page

Comment: @AleksandrIvashchenko So I guess this will not affect the cart behavior? When I try to add a product to cart from home page, it will not actually add it. And that's the only difference in the url that I can spot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are comparing URLs for two different products.  You should pick the same product for both (id 17 and 44). That will make it easier to spot the differences between the URL.

$this is really important -- while the function names are identical, they are obviously different functions.

One thing that may be breaking the Add to Cart is the different "form_key" value (which Magento added in v1.8 to minimize XSS attacks).  As I understand it, this should the same key through the session, and Magento might be rejecting it because it doesn't match.

/template/catalog/productwidget/* is NOT A DEFAULT FEATURE.  This might be added by an extension or is your custom development. Check and see what the Block class (enable template path hints with block name) is for this and see if you can find the function. Then compare the functions and see what is different.

Comment: Dear @Phil, I was careless, I've updated the question. It was `product/widget/` atcually.

Comment: I enabled path hints and block name. In the category page, it's Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List; and for the home page, it's Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New. They both extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract and have no getAddToCartUrl(). So I think they use the same function from Abstract. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Well there is a widget folder in base/default, but no sale... so it is still custom development, so try to look at what I mentioned with Template Path Hints.  Thank you for updating the question with the same product.  As far as I can tell, the "uenc" would not affect the adding to the cart... its just a base64 encoded version of the referrer page.  So something else is breaking it... add logging to the add() function in Mage_Checkout_CartController (and revert after finished) to track down where its breaking.

Comment: Hi @Phil, I'm not familiar with logging in Magento. Is there any article you would recommend to lead me through the process? I was able to find CartController and addAction(), just not sure what exactly needs to be done for logging.

Comment: You could use die('got here') to step through major areas in the code... if it doesn't die and display a blank screen then it didn't hit it.  But for non-blocking and invisible (to browser) comments you can also use Mage::log(). Tutorial for that here: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/create-your-own-log-files-with-magelog/